# Fusion installing Mavericks this item is temporary unavailable

Tags: macos, vmware

I am new to Mac. I have a MacBook Air running 10.9.4.

I installed Fusion VMWare and I am trying to install a VM for 10.9.4 using the "Install OS X from the recovery partition. When I get to the installation step that asks for my Apple Id, I log in and get this message: "This item is temporarily unavailable - Try again later".

Why???

Couple things to note: This Mac was passed down to me, I do not have a Mavericks installer and never purchased one.

Answer (score 1):

The only 'official' way to get 10.9.x [which would actually be 10.9.5] is to have previously 'bought' it - it would then be in your previous purchases list on the App Store & could be re-downloaded.

Alternatively, if that was the OS that was on the machine when new you can get it via [Internet Recovery](http://support.apple.com/en-us/HT4718).

Otherwise, the only OS available to download will be Yosemite.

Comment: I am not able to load Mavericks on a machine that originally came with it via the "Install OS X from the recovery partition". I get the same "Temporarily unavailable error" as above. Pretty sure it's permanently unavailable.

Comment: The recovery partition should install the current OS that is on that partition. Internet Recovery will install the one the machine came with.

Comment: When I tried to install from the recovery partition, it asked me for the iTunes login. After providing my iTunes login, I got the "item is temporarily unavailable" message. I have not been able to proceed.

Comment: Ahhh... ***your*** ID... which I'm guessing was not the original ID that 'purchased' Mavericks in the first place - that's why it's not available, you never owned it. Did you not completely wipe & re-install the OS when you first got the machine?

Comment: I'm not the OP, just giving more information. I *believe* in my case I was logging in with the Apple ID that was originally used to register the machine.

Comment: @Tetsujin I'm having a similar issue.  How do you completely wipe and reinstall the OS?  I've deleted the partitions and recreated, and during reinstall (from recovery partition), I get the "blocked symbol" (circle with diagonal slash). Attempting internet recovery and entering my AppleID just brings me to the "this item is temporarily unavailable" error message.

Answer (score 0):

I was able to solve this problem by installing Mac OS X Mavericks installer. 
First I download Mavericks installer from [this](http://getintopc.com/softwares/operating-systems/mac-os-x-mavericks-free-download/) link.

Then I made a bootable USB using disk utility. You can see how to do that in [this](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=PAGlyS82Te8) video. If the link does not work, you can find the video on youtube by searching for: "how to burn OS X Lion to USB DVD". 
Put a USB stick into your Mac (8 GB minimum) and go to Disk Utility. Make the USB bootable following these steps: select erase data, create a single partition, click options and choose the first option (GUID). After this, click on download OS X Mavericks files and than click Restore and select the downloaded OS X Mavericks file as source file and USB in destination. This will take some time.

Now, when you receive the error, put in the bootable USB stick with OS X and press command + R. Reinstall it install automatically.